# como hacer unas figuras con funciones en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, css

asi tengo la tabla , obviamnate con 2 TR adicionales mas con las clases correspondiente

1. codigo tabla

   ```
        <table class="table1">
   <tr>
     <th>Color</th>
     <th>Forma</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="color" onclick="cambiarRojo()" id="rojo" />Rojo
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="figura" onclick="figura_cruz();" />Cruz
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="color" onclick="cambiarAmarillo()" id="amarillo" />Amarillo
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="figura" onclick="figura_cuadrado();" />Cuadrado
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="color" onclick="cambiarVerde()" id="verde" />Verde
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="figura" onclick="figura_triangulo();" />Triangulo
     </td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. js

este código estoy usando , lo que quiero es que al seleccionar la figura, que  los cuadros de las clases seleccionada desaparezcan , lo realiza pero no los cuadros que quiero

```
 let clases = ['cuadrob', 'cuadroc', 'cuadrod',

    'cuadrof','cuadroh','cuadroj','cuadrok','cuadrol','cuadron','cuadroo',
    'cuadrop','cuadror','cuadrot','cuadrov','cuadrow', 'cuadrox'];

  function figura_cruz(){
   for(let clasesCruz of clases){
    var cruz = document.getElementsByClassName(clasesCruz);   
    for(var i=0; i<cruz.length; i++){
    if(cruz[i].style.visibility = "hidden"){
        cruz[i].style.display = "block";
    }else{
        cruz[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    }
   } 


    }
```

3. js cambio color esta es una de la function que realize para el cambio de color rojo, amarillo y verde

   ```
    function cambiarRojo() {
   var Filas = document.getElementsByClassName("clase");
   [].forEach.call(Filas, function (rojo) {
   rojo.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   });
   }
   ```

Comment: pon el código , no imágenes

Comment: ya pude subir el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunos problemas en el codigo que hacen que no resulte: en la comparacion del if se usa `==` en vez de `=` (de otro modo siempre sera evaluado `true`). Ademas, solo basta usar `style.visibility` para mostrar /ocultar la celda. Si lo haces con `display:none` la celda desaparecera y otro elemento ocupara su lugar (equivale a que la celda no esté)

```js
 let clases = ['cuadrob', 'cuadroc', 'cuadrod',

    'cuadrof','cuadroh','cuadroj','cuadrok','cuadrol','cuadron','cuadroo',
    'cuadrop','cuadror','cuadrot','cuadrov','cuadrow', 'cuadrox'];

  function figura_cruz(){
   for(let clasesCruz of clases){
    var cruz = document.getElementsByClassName(clasesCruz);   
    for(var i=0; i<cruz.length; i++){
    if(cruz[i].style.visibility == "hidden"){
        cruz[i].style.visibility = "";
    }else{
        cruz[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    }
   } 

}

figura_cruz();
```

```css
td{
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
      <td class="clase  cuadroa" ></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadrob"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadroc"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadrod"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadroe"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="clase  cuadrof"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadrog"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadroh"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadroi"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadroj"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="clase  cuadrok"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadrol"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadrom"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadron"></td>
      <td class="clase  cuadroo"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la aclaración , ya voy comprendiendo un poco mas la lógica , soy nuevo llevo poco estudiando ,muy agradecido por tomar parte de tu tiempo , saludos